# sql server date range based on previous row entries

Tags: sql-server

I've tried searching this up, but nothing really matched with what I was looking for, so any help is appreciated!

I've got a table like below:

```
+-----------+---------------+-------+------------+  
| Policy_NO | Creation_Date | Limit | Limit_Date |  
+-----------+---------------+-------+------------+  
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |  1000 | 8/31/2015  |  
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |  2000 | 9/30/2015  |  
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |  5000 | 10/22/2015 |  
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |   500 | 11/17/2015 |  
| A00003    | 9/21/2015     |  3000 | 1/1/2016   |  
+-----------+---------------+-------+------------+
```

And what I want is to have an 'End_Limit_Date' which should either be the date of the next limit with the same policy number -1 or exactly one year from the Creation date.

For example, the table above should be:

```
+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|  Policy_NO  Creation_Date  Limit  Limit_Date   | End_Limit_Date |
+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| A00001     8/31/2015       1000  8/31/2015     | 9/29/2015      |
| A00001     8/31/2015       2000  9/30/2015     | 10/21/2015     |
| A00001     8/31/2015       5000  10/22/2015    | 11/16/2015     |
| A00001     8/31/2015        500  11/17/2015    | 8/31/2016      |
| A00003     9/21/2015       3000  1/1/2016      | 9/21/2016      |
+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

I only have read-only access, so 'update queries' and 'create new table' queries are not applicable for my case...

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SQL Server 2012 or later you can use [`LEAD()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213125.aspx) to get the next row:

```
SELECT  t.Policy_NO,
        t.Creation_Date,
        t.Limit,
        t.Limit_Date,
        End_Limit_Date = ISNULL(
                            DATEADD(DAY, -1, LEAD(t.Limit_Date) OVER(PARTITION BY t.Policy_NO 
                                                                    ORDER BY t.Limit_Date)), 
                            DATEADD(YEAR, 1, t.Creation_Date))
FROM    dbo.T;
```

If not, you will need a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  t.Policy_NO,
        t.Creation_Date,
        t.Limit,
        t.Limit_Date,
        End_Limit_Date = ISNULL(
                            DATEADD(DAY, -1, t2.Limit_Date), 
                            DATEADD(YEAR, 1, t.Creation_Date))
FROM    dbo.T 
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 t2.Limit_Date
            FROM    dbo.T AS t2
            WHERE   t2.Policy_NO = t.Policy_NO
            AND     t2.Limit_Date > t.Limit_Date
            ORDER BY t2.Limit_Date
        ) AS t2;
```

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Farellia Did you verify the solution? Asking because I ran @GarethD 's query and the End_Limit_Date for A00003 yields `2016-09-21` instead of `2017-01-01`

Comment: Yes, the only thing missing is the 1Y part, but that's the part I can figure out.

Comment: @CM2K That looks to me like an error in the sample data, the brief was *"exactly one year from the creation date."*, and the creation date for A00003 is `2015-09-21`, I would therefore expect the end date to be `2016-09-21`. It looks like in the sample data it has added 1 year to the limit date, but this is not what has happened for `A00001`. So I had to assume the description was right, and the sample data wrong.

Comment: @GarethD you got the description right, I was wrong but OP maybe you can clarify. Is the `End_Limit` used for `End_Limit_Date` for A00003 or the Creation_Date???

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I did type in my sample data wrong, and GarethD was correct in following my description. Thank you both for catching that.